How to instantiate a model?
I'm new to NodeJs/Sequelize. I have declared this model :
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Ingredient extends Model {

    static associate(models) {
      Ingredient.belongsTo(models.Department, { foreignKey: 'departmentId' });
    }
  };
  Ingredient.init({
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    name:
    {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    departmentId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    }
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Ingredient',
  });
  return Ingredient;
};

And in my ingredient.controler, in create() method I try to instanciate an Ingredient with :
 const ingredient = Ingredient.build({
    name: req.body.name,
    departmentId: req.body.departmentId,
  })

as said in their doc, but I get an error :

Ingredient.build is not a function

I also tried with a new()
  const ingredient = new Ingredient({
     name: req.body.name,
     departmentId: req.body.departmentId,
  });

but I also get an error :

Ingredient is not a constructor

What do I miss?

Actually I found the answer here : Sequelize: create is not a function when model is generated from migration
In controller I had :
const Ingredient = require("../models/ingredient.js");

but it should be :
const db = require('../models/index');
...
const ingredient = db.Ingredient.build({
    name: req.body.name,
    departmentId: req.body.departmentId,
})

All fine now :)

I use the create() method.
Here is an example from the documentation:
const jane = await User.create({ name: 'Jane' });
// console.log(jane); // Don't do this
console.log(jane.toJSON()); // This is good!
console.log(JSON.stringify(jane, null, 4)); // This is also good!

In your code, it would be something like:
 const ingredient = await Ingredient.create({
    name: req.body.name,
    departmentId: req.body.departmentId,
  })


Make sure the callback for your controller is defined with the async keyword for the await keyword to work.
